# Group identifiers/values that are related with each other between multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query, azure-synapse

I want to group identifiers that are related with each other between multiple columns and create/assign a unique group id.

Also, If we receive a new row, we can assign the right id  respecting what has been done before for others group id

For example:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | Null | 33 | 12 |
| BB | Null | 45 | 12 |
| AA | 123 | 65 | 15 |
| CC | 123 | NULL | 42 |
| DD | Null | 10 | 42 |
| EE | NULL | 20 | NULL |
| FF | 145 | 33 | NULL |
| GG | NULL | NULL | 11 |

Desired result:

The group ID =1 beacuse in col1, it's the same value row 1 and 3 (AA) and for row 4 it's also ID 1 because in the second column, the value for AA it's 123 (the same for CC)
If there is any match between rows and cross the columns, we generate an id

| Col1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Group ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | Null | 33 | 12 | 1 |
| BB | Null | 45 | 12 | 1 |
| AA | 123 | 65 | 15 | 1 |
| CC | 123 | NULL | 42 | 1 |
| DD | Null | 10 | 42 | 1 |
| EE | NULL | 20 | NULL | 2 |
| FF | 145 | 33 | NULL | 1 |
| GG | NULL | NULL | 11 | 3 |

Comment: How are you deriving that grouping column?  I don't see any commonality.  BTW, please don't post images of data, put it in your post.

Comment: It's azure synapse or sql server?  Does synapse allow common table expressions?

Comment: @SteveC I try to find a solution in azure and sql server! but yes.. i need it for azure synapse!

Comment: @Andrew thx for the advice! sorry I'm new! and I put an explanation before the output table if it is clear!

Comment: I don't think this would be possible in a single SQL statement. You probably need to write a script (SQL or otherwise), go over multiple iterations. As there is no logic per se to defining group id, and rules to identify what group a row belongs to are pretty simple but tedious.

Comment: Couple questions for you- it might be doable in a single statement, but it depends a lot on specifically what you are trying to do. How are you planning to do the insert, especially for this column? Do you need to calculate the column for existing data or just inserts? Are additional inserts single or multiple rows at a time (is it possible we'll need to add more than one new ID?). Do the ID's need to be sequential, or could we generate a ROW_NUMBER and take the minimum for the group?

Comment: @SamaraSoucy the table is build by concatenation of 3 other tables. after the building of this table, we will receive multiple rows after! I don't understand the question about calculate column? if you talk about the id.. yes we need to generate id and it doesn't need to be sequential ! a rank or rownum can be possible but after grouping identifiers, they all have the same id!

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some work on this and agree with Kashyap- I cannot find a way to do this is a single statement. You need either a recursive CTE or a loop. Synapse does not currently support recursive CTEs, which leaves using a loop to create the effect you want.

One concern that came up while I was working with this. As you continue to add data, you'll have more and more overlaps and could eventually end up with just one group. That depends on your dataset- you might have something you can guarantee will have discrete divisions. The way the script I put together works, a new match will update any group IDs, even in existing data. You could modify it to only set group IDs only for new rows, but then you could end up in a situation when one row matches multiple groups.

Certainly not the only option, but this is the script I pulled together. It is dependent on having a unique ID that will remain the same in each iteration. Because the loop uses updates instead of inserts, prepping the data would involve inserting the data into your new table without the group, and you can create your ID at that time using auto-increment or otherwise. The script works best with an INT ID column, but should work with a guid if that is necessary.

So process is essentially this:

1. Do whatever initial prep you need to do to inserting data into the table and creating an ID
2. Join the table back onto itself, once for each column that could contain a match
3. Update the Group ID to be the minimum value across the IDs and current group IDs of that set of matches.
4. Check to see if we need to do another round. Because we are using minimum ID as a group number, there will be a row where the `ID = group ID` in each group

````
CREATE TABLE #testtable
  (
     [id]          INT NOT NULL,
     [col1]        INT NOT NULL,
     [col2]        INT NULL,
     [col3]        INT NULL,
     [groupnumber] INT NULL
  )

INSERT INTO #testtable
            (id,
             col1,
             col2,
             col3)
INSERT INTO #testTable (id, col1, col2, col3) 
    SELECT 1, 1, 5, 33 UNION ALL         -- First
    SELECT 2, 2, null, 45 UNION ALL      -- Second
    SELECT 3, 1, 123, 65 UNION ALL       -- First
    SELECT 4, 3, 123, null UNION ALL     -- First
    SELECT 5, 10, null, 10 UNION ALL      -- Third
    SELECT 6, 5, null, 45 UNION ALL      -- Second
    SELECT 7, 6, 145, 33                -- First


DECLARE @RemainingRows INT,
    @LoopCounter INT, @MaxLoops int             -- To protect against infinite loop
    
SET @RemainingRows = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM #testtable)
SET @LoopCounter = 0;
SET @MaxLoops = 10;
    
WHILE( @RemainingRows > 0 
    AND @LoopCounter < @MaxLoops ) 
BEGIN

    WITH combineddata AS 
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            col1,
            col2,
            col3,
            groupnumber
        FROM
            #testtable
    ),
    --Create a set a rows that contains all rows and all possible matches
    matcheddata AS 
    (
        SELECT
            c1.id,
            c1.col1 AS c1col1,
            c1.col2 AS c1col2,
            c1.col3 AS c1col3,
            c1.groupnumber AS groupNumber1,
            c2.id AS RowNum2,
            c2.groupnumber AS groupNumber2,
            c3.id AS RowNum3,
            c3.groupnumber AS groupNumber3,
            c4.id AS RowNum4,
            c4.groupnumber AS groupNumber4 
        FROM
            combineddata c1 
            LEFT JOIN
                combineddata c2 
                ON c1.col1 = c2.col1 
            LEFT JOIN
                combineddata c3 
                ON c1.col2 = c3.col2 
            LEFT JOIN
                combineddata c4 
                ON c1.col3 = c4.col3
    )
    UPDATE #testtable 
    SET
        groupnumber = 
            CASE
                WHEN
                    NEW.groupnumber IS NULL 
                THEN
                    NULL 
                ELSE
                    NEW.groupnumber 
            END
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                id,
                c1col1,
                c1col2,
                c1col3,
                MIN(groupnumber) AS GroupNumber 
            FROM
                matcheddata CROSS apply (
                SELECT
                    MIN(c) AS GroupNumber 
                FROM (VALUES 
                    (id), 
                    (RowNum2), 
                    (RowNum3), 
                    (RowNum4),
                    (groupNumber1),
                    (groupNumber2),
                    (groupNumber3),
                    (groupNumber4)
                ) AS v (C)
                WHERE
                    c IS NOT NULL) g 
                GROUP BY
                    id,
                    c1col1,
                    c1col2,
                    c1col3
        ) NEW 
    INNER JOIN # testtable 
        ON NEW.id = #testtable.id 
        
    SET
        @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1 
    SET
        @RemainingRows = 
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(t1.id) 
            FROM
                #testtable t1 
                LEFT JOIN
                    #testtable t2 
                    ON t1.groupnumber = t2.[id] 
            WHERE
                t2.id IS NULL 
                OR t2.id <> t2.groupnumber
        )
        
        PRINT 'Remaining Rows: ' + CAST(@RemainingRows AS VARCHAR) PRINT 'Counter: ' + CAST(@LoopCounter AS VARCHAR);
END

SELECT * FROM #testtable 

IF Object_id('tempdb..#testTable') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE # testtable 
    END```
````